# UIScrollView not receiving scroll action

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

In the app I am working on, my goal right now is to scroll content when the keyboard shows and to allow users to scroll while it is showing. I have tried a few different solutions and none have been able to achieve this yet.

I'm using storyboards in the app and here is the element hierarchy within the view controller:

View Controller
    UIScrollView
         UIView
             Buttons/textfields/labels/UIPickerView

I first set the UIScrollView's content size to be the same size of the view that was inside of it holding all of the form elements. When that didn't work, I tried over-exagerating the height of the content manually setting the content size to be 320 x 2000. Again, that didn't work. I have user interaction enabled set to YES on the scroll view as well. This is the code I have in there at this point.

```
CGSize contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 2000);
[self.scrollView setContentSize:contentSize];
```

Within the scroll view I had a button that sits behind the whole form that has an action to close the keyboard if a user touches outside of it. I disabled that to see if it may have been a conflict in events that would keep it from scrolling. Again, didn't work.

```
-(IBAction)closeKeyboard:(id)sender
{
    if(![self isFirstResponder]){
        [self.view endEditing:YES];
    }
}
```

I even set up some observers to see if the keyboard is about to appear or disappear. The observers would adjust the height of the scroll view, not the content size, just the scroll view itself, based on where the keyboard was currently sitting. So at this point, the content in the scroll view would be much taller than the scroll view itself, but still no scrolling is happening.

Here is the code for my observers:

```
// adjust view based on keyboard
- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)n
{
    NSDictionary* userInfo = [n userInfo];

    // get the size of the keyboard
    CGSize keyboardSize = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;


    // resize the scrollview
    CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
    // I'm also subtracting a constant kTabBarHeight because my UIScrollView was offset by the UITabBar so really only the portion of the keyboard that is leftover pass the UITabBar is obscuring my UIScrollView.
    //viewFrame.size.height += keyboardSize.height;

    CGRect scrollRect = CGRectMake(viewFrame.origin.x, viewFrame.origin.y, viewFrame.size.width, viewFrame.size.height + keyboardSize.height + 100);

    [UIScrollView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
     [UIScrollView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIScrollView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    [self.scrollView setFrame:scrollRect];
    self.scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [UIScrollView commitAnimations];

    keyboardShowing = false;
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)n
{
    // This is an ivar I'm using to ensure that we do not do the frame size adjustment on    the UIScrollView if the keyboard is already shown.  This can happen if the user, after fixing editing a UITextField, scrolls the resized UIScrollView to another UITextField and attempts to edit the next UITextField.  If we were to resize the UIScrollView again, it would be disastrous.  NOTE: The keyboard notification will fire even when the keyboard is already shown.
   if (keyboardShowing) {
      return;
   }

   NSDictionary* userInfo = [n userInfo];

   // get the size of the keyboard
    CGSize keyboardSize = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

   // resize the noteView
   CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
   // I'm also subtracting a constant kTabBarHeight because my UIScrollView was offset by the UITabBar so really only the portion of the keyboard that is leftover pass the UITabBar is obscuring my UIScrollView.

   CGRect scrollRect = CGRectMake(viewFrame.origin.x, viewFrame.origin.y, viewFrame.size.width, viewFrame.size.height - keyboardSize.height - 100);
   //scrollView.frame.size.height -= keyboardSize.height;

    //viewFrame.size.height -= keyboardSize.height;
    [UIScrollView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIScrollView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIScrollView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    [self.scrollView setFrame:scrollRect];
    self.scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [UIScrollView commitAnimations];

    keyboardShowing = YES;
}
```

I would not be surprised if this is one of those simple mistakes that keeps slipping my mind, but this sort of accessibility feature would be really nice to have in the app. Any help would be much appreciated, or even other possible solutions to the problem I am trying to solve would be great too.

Comment: did you inlcude `UIScrollViewDelegate` in your interface?

Comment: Wow. Of course it would be something simple like that -.- Thanks! Its nice to have a second set of eyes.

Comment: New issue though, when I re-enabled the tap to close keyboard code, the scrolling doesn't work because of the tap action. How would I get the app to tell the difference?

Comment: Can you add the code that you use to close the keyboard to your question?

Comment: It has been updated with the code

Comment: I'll add some alternate keyboard closing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using a gesture recognizer in IB to detect a tap outside event. Because this recognizer is in the highest view in the hierarchy, it overrides the scrollview's detectors. You might need to change it slightly depending on which areas you want to be able to tap on to close the keyboard.

This is the [UIResponder class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html). It lists all of the UIResponder events that your view controller automatically inherits. What might fix your problem is subclassing your UIScrollView and adding the keyboard closing code to it. Also, make sure that you set it to the first responder.

**Final code that worked:**

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    mouseSwiped = NO;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if ([touch tapcount] == 1)
       for(UIView *view in self.view.subviews){
           if([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]){
               [view resignFirstResponder];
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: I added your code with a few adjustments to match how my view is set up, but still no change. Touch drag still closes the keyboard instead of scrolling the view.

Comment: Which class did you add the code to/was the original code in? Also, did you remove the gesture recognizer?

Comment: It wasn't a gesture recognizer, it was a button that sat behind all of the other elements. either way, yes I removed that. The code is in the view controller I am using. Is it possible to get the program to differentiate between types of events like that in the same space?

Comment: This is odd, it isn't a problem that I've had with scrollviews. And yes, there are different methods in the apple APIs, I'll see if I can update my answer with what you are looking for.

Comment: It did not work when I put the code in the touchesBegan, since it would be as soon as someone's finger hits the screen, but it did work in the touchesEnded. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Mind posting the final method code inside of the answer? It could be helpful for anyone else looking for a solution to this problem.